# Как в аннотации типов правильно указать тип возвращаемый функцией?

Tags: python, типы

```
def send_comment(request, article_id: int) -> JsonResponse(dict[str: int | str]) | HttpResponseBadRequest(str):
    is_ajax = request.is_ajax()
    if is_ajax and request.user.is_authenticated:
        comment_text = request.POST['comment-text']
        try:
            parent_id = request.POST['parent_id']
            article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
            parent = article.comment_set.get(id=parent_id)
            comment = article.comment_set.create(comment_text=comment_text, comment_author=request.user, reply=parent)
        except:
            article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)
            comment = article.comment_set.create(comment_text=comment_text, comment_author=request.user)
        data = {
            'total_likes': get_fans(comment).count(),
            'comment_id': comment.id,
            'comment_author': str(comment.comment_author)
        }
        comment.save()
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request')
```

Ошибка TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'
Как нужно правильно указать в аннотации, что должна возвращать функция. Использую python 3.10

Comment: До какой-то версии нужно `Union` использовать вместо `|`, но до какой точно не помню. Мне казалось до `3.10`, но может до `3.11` всё-таки.

Comment: А, тут наверное проблема в другом, нужно скорее всего так для словаря: `dict[str, int | str]`, двоеточие там не к месту.

Comment: Всё равно не помогло. Само ide начинает говорить, что не правильный тип данных

Comment: Если это Django, то просто укажите `HttpResponse` и не мучайтесь, наверное?

Comment: ide будет говорить, что возвращаться должен ещё и jsonResponse, а если его тоже поставить, то будет такая же ошибка

Comment: JsonResponse является потомком HttpResponse (и HttpResponseBadRequest тоже является потомком HttpResponse), поэтому нормальная ide не должна ничего говорить и ничего лишнего ставить не надо

Comment: Спасибо, всё сработало.

Comment: Напишите тогда в виде ответа - какой итоговый вариант кода нормально сработал.